# TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and typescript and came across this error

> TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'.

It occured in this codepiece on "name.length" I want the function only to work if the length of the string 'name' is greater than or equal to 3 characters.

```
  processForm() {
   if(name.length>=3){
    const allInfo = `My name is ${this.name}....`;
    alert(allInfo);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Where you have user `never` in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `name` is a property / field in the component or class, you need to use `this.name` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to add -

1. Use `this.name` instead of `name` (if it's class variable)
2. Add check on variable existance like this -

   ```
   processForm() {
     if(name && name.length>=3){
       const allInfo = `My name is ${this.name}....`;
       alert(allInfo);
     }
   }
   ```